# Change DIV BG on every Click from another DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one problem with my JQuery script.

I must change Div (mother) background on EVERY click from another div's but these DIV have backgrounds so I must change from CHILDER to MOTHER div background.

This is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".room-gallery .sub-images .sub-image").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentImage = $(".sub-image").css("background");
    $(".main-picture").css("background", currentImage);
  });
})
```

```html
<!-- Gallery Start -->
<div class="room-gallery">
  <div class="col-md-12 clear">
    <div class="main-picture" style="background: url(images/gallery/img-1.jpg) center center no-repeat;">
      <a href="#main-picture"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 sub-images clear">
    <div class="sub-image" style="background: url(images/gallery/img-2.jpg) center center no-repeat;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 sub-images clear">
    <div class="sub-image" style="background: url(images/gallery/img-3.jpg) center center no-repeat;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 sub-images clear">
    <div class="sub-image" style="background: url(images/gallery/img-4.jpg) center center no-repeat;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Gallery End -->
```

So I must change DIV background into .main-picture on EVERY click on .sub-images.

I dont know what I doing wrong :(

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what You want is:

```
var currentImage = $(this).css("background");
```

instead of:

```
var currentImage = $(".sub-image").css("background");
```

because now it selects first div with class `.sub-image` in DOM